# Module that converts ASCII to 7-segment display using FPGA

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga

I have a question about the meaning of having a `begin` statement for each letter. Why is it necessary or is it? Also, what does the `HexSeg[x] = y` mean for the letters with a `begin` statement? I am having difficulty wrapping my head around it. Is all of this necessary and is there an easier way to go about this? Is it the same method for coding ASCII numbers? I am also using the DE10-Lite FPGA board.

```
//
// ASCII to 7-segment display conversion
//
module ASCII27Seg (input [7:0] AsciiCode, output reg [6:0] HexSeg);
    always @ (*) begin
        HexSeg = 7'd0;      // initialization of variable HexSeg
        $display("AsciiCode %b", AsciiCode);
        case (AsciiCode)
            // A
            8'h41 : HexSeg[3] = 1;
            // a
            8'h61 : HexSeg[3] = 1;
            // B
            8'h42 : begin
                HexSeg[0] = 1; HexSeg[1] = 1;
            end
            // b
            8'h62 : begin
                HexSeg[0] = 1; HexSeg[1] = 1;
            end
            // C
            8'h43 : begin
                HexSeg[1] = 1; HexSeg[2] = 1; HexSeg[6] = 1;
            end
            // c
            8'h63 : begin
                HexSeg[1] = 1; HexSeg[2] = 1; HexSeg[6] = 1;
            end
//
// the rest of the code should go here
//
            // D
            8'h44 : begin

            // d
            8'h64 : begin

            // E
            8'h45 : begin

            // e
            8'h65 : begin

            // F
            8'h46 : begin

            // f
            8'h66 : begin

            // G
            8'h47 : begin

            // g
            8'h67 : begin

            // H
            8'h48 : begin

            // h
            8'h68 : begin

            // I
            8'h49 : begin

            // i
            8'h69 : begin

            // J
            8'h4A : begin

            // j
            8'h6A : begin

            // K
            8'h4B : begin

            // k
            8'h6B : begin

            // L
            8'h4C : begin

            // l
            8'h6C : begin

            // M
            8'h4D : begin

            // m
            8'h6D : begin

            // N
            8'h4E : begin

            // n
            8'h6E : begin

            // O
            8'h4F : begin

            // o
            8'h6F : begin

            // P
            8'h50 : begin

            // p
            8'h70 : begin

            // Q
            8'h51 : begin

            // q
            8'h71 : begin

            // R
            8'h52 : begin

            // r
            8'h72 : begin

            // S
            8'h53 : begin

            // s
            8'h73 : begin

            // T
            8'h54 : begin

            // t
            8'h74 : begin

            // U
            8'h55 : begin

            // u
            8'h75 : begin

            // V
            8'h56 : begin

            // v
            8'h76 : begin

            // W
            8'h57 : begin

            // w
            8'h77 : begin

            // X
            8'h58 : begin

            // x
            8'h78 : begin

            // Y
            8'h59 : begin

            // y
            8'h79 : begin

            // Z
            8'h5A : begin

            // z
            8'h7A : begin

            // turn all the bits off by default
            default : HexSeg = 8'b11111111;     // default of variable HexSeg
// you have to finish this code using correct syntax, see begin and end, and case
// and endcase in language specification, and be careful.
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

I tried implementing the `begin` statements for every letter, but I don't understand why it wasn't necessary for 'A' and 'a'. I also don't know how to form the `begin` statements with `HexSeg[x]`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `begin/end` keywords are *required* by Verilog whenever you have more than one statement in a block of code.  They are *optional* if you only have one statement in the block.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 12.5 *Case statement*.

Each `case` item in the `case` statement can execute a block of code.  For example, `8'h41` is the 1st `case` item.  Since that item only has one statement (`HexSeg[3] = 1;`), the `begin/end` keywords are not needed.  However, for the `8'h42` item, you have 2 statements (`HexSeg[0] = 1; HexSeg[1] = 1;`), and the `begin/end` keywords are needed.

> what does the HexSeg[x] = y mean for the letters with a begin
> statement?

It means the same thing with or without the `begin`; you are just setting bits of `HexSeg`.

Since some of the items require at least 2 statements, you must use `begin/end` for those items, as just described.  However, from a consistent code style perspective, you might prefer to have all items look the same.  Here is how that would look:

```
module ASCII27Seg (input [7:0] AsciiCode, output reg [6:0] HexSeg);
    always @ (*) begin
        HexSeg = 7'd0;
        case (AsciiCode)
            // A
            8'h41 : begin 
                HexSeg[3] = 1;
            end
            // a
            8'h61 : begin
                HexSeg[3] = 1;
            end
            // B
            8'h42 : begin
                HexSeg[0] = 1; HexSeg[1] = 1;
            end
            // b
            8'h62 : begin
                HexSeg[0] = 1; HexSeg[1] = 1;
            end
            // C
            8'h43 : begin
                HexSeg[1] = 1; HexSeg[2] = 1; HexSeg[6] = 1;
            end
            // c
            8'h63 : begin
                HexSeg[1] = 1; HexSeg[2] = 1; HexSeg[6] = 1;
            end
            // turn all the bits off by default
            default : begin
                HexSeg = 8'b11111111;
            end
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

This is a little more typing, but it may be easier to read and understand using this style.

> is there an easier way to go about this?

This is a good straightforward approach.  Using a `case` statement is a common practice for this sort of design.

> Is it the same method for coding ASCII numbers?

Yes, if you need to do a similar mapping between 8-bit ASCII and 7-bit `HexSeg`.

---

Whenever you are setting *consecutive* bits, you could combine them into a single statement using a range specifier.  This is optional.  For example:

```
        8'h43 : begin
                HexSeg[2:1] = 2'b11; HexSeg[6] = 1; // 2 statements
```

---

Whenever you execute the same statements for multiple `case` items, you can combine the items, separating them by commas.  For example, `a` and `A` execute the same statements:

```
module ASCII27Seg (input [7:0] AsciiCode, output reg [6:0] HexSeg);
    always @ (*) begin
        HexSeg = 7'd0;
        case (AsciiCode)
            // A, a
            8'h41, 8'h61 : begin
                HexSeg[3] = 1;
            end
            // B, b
            8'h42, 8'h62 : begin
                HexSeg[0] = 1; HexSeg[1] = 1;
            end
            // C, c
            8'h43, 8'h63 : begin
                HexSeg[1] = 1; HexSeg[2] = 1; HexSeg[6] = 1;
            end
            // turn all the bits off by default
            default : begin
                HexSeg = 8'b11111111;
            end
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```